# DataGrid WPF: gray line in the middle

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, line

As you can see on my screenshot, I have a gray line in the middle of my DataGrid, after 20th element of the grid. It only happens if there is enough data, and does not move with the elements: it just stays there when scrolling.

[image]

I've been searched for options that can activate this, but couldn't find something similar. Probably my search terms are wrong, that's why I'm asking.

I've simplified as much as possible, here is my XAML:

```
<Grid Margin="5,10,5,5" MaxHeight="600" MinWidth="800" MaxWidth="800">
    <DataGrid Name="DataGridTest" GridLinesVisibility="None">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Here is my C#:

```
public class TestData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Hello : Window
{
    public Hello()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<TestData> testData = new List<TestData>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            testData.Add(new TestData { Name = ("name" + i) });

        DataGridTest.ItemsSource = testData;
    }
}
```

I'm using .NET 5 on a Desktop WPF app.

Thanks for any insight that could be of help!

Comment: Possibly related to the MaxHeight property you have set? Try removing that property and see if it goes away.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Sadly doesn't go away when removing all `Grid` properties either.

Comment: Try setting the AllowPaging property to false? Documentation says the default is false, so I'm not sure why that would be happening. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.allowpaging could also set the page size to different values to see if it relates to pagination.

Comment: @bbarrett Sorry, I edited my first post: I'm using .NET 5 on a WPF Desktop app. Your property seems to only be on previous versions with ASP.NET.

Comment: If this is of any help, setting `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"` to the DataGrid makes the behavior of this strange line different: now it disappears when scrolling up to a certain point, then reappears, etc.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a problem trying to scale the page. Because for me it appears on line 23. The line appears or does not appear, depending on whether you reduce or enlarge the page.
If the Grid's `VerticalAlignment` property is set, this does not appear to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after fiddling around with this for a few hours, it's definitely due to sizing. I don't know how, but I had some nested StackPanels that where also influencing this behavior. Tried to replace them with Grids, and the same problem occurred when nesting them. I rewrote all from scratch and it started working, so I guess some attributes where wrong and that the DataGrid can be very sensitive to this. Still don't know exactly what attribute was causing this, but in case anyone has a similar problem: try to simplify to the max!